# Subset of normed Linear Space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

The problem in question is as follows:

"Show that the set $P$ of all polynomials on the segment $[a,b]$ is a linear space. For $P$ considered as a subset of the normed linear space $C_[a,b]$ with the norm

$||f(x)||$ = $max_{a{\leq}x{\leq}b}$ $|f(x)|$

Show that $P$ fails to be closed. "

The first part of this question is trivial as we can just show linearity through addition, scalar multiplication and distributivity.

However, I'm having a hard time understanding how the norm gives me information about the closure of the set. Perhaps I'm thinking about closure wrong as it relates to normed spaces wrong but any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, they are many way to show it, for example consider the taylor development of $exp,sin,...$ for example, $e^x=\sum_{n\geq 0}{{x^n}\over{n!}}$ is a limit of polynomial functions, but $e^x$ is not a polynomial function. More generally Stone-Weirstrass says that polynomial functions are dense in the set of real valued continuous function defined on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

For the ultimate in (counter)examples, you can quote the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. It tells you that the space of polynomials is dense in the space of continuous functions. so the closure is everything in sight.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the Weierstrass Approximation theorem?

http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~speicher/Section14.pdf

This pdf does a good job explaining it. But the statement of the theorem should be enough alone, for your purposes: there are continuous functions which are not polynomials, but by the theorem, are the uniform limit of polynomials.